# How can I find duplicate with same word and same topic?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below.
Table name is 'Test'.

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | word     | topic    |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | plus     | math     |
|  2 | minus    | math     |
|  3 | multiple | math     |
|  4 | minus    | math     |
|  5 | cpu      | computer |
|  6 | click    | computer |
|  7 | monitor  | computer |
|  8 | cpu      | computer |
|  9 | multiple | computer |
+----+----------+----------+
```

How can I find duplicate word with same topic?

I want result like below.

```
 +----+----------+----------+
 | id | word     | topic    |
 +----+----------+----------+
 |  2 | minus    | math     |
 |  4 | minus    | math     |
 |  5 | cpu      | computer |
 |  8 | cpu      | computer |
 +----+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need separate rows for each `id`, you can do:

```
select word, topic, group_concat(id)
from t
group by word, topic
having count(*) > 1
```

Aggregation can be rather expensive, so if you do want the original rows, `exists` is an option:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.word = t.word and t2.topic = t.topic and t2.id <> t.id
             );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(word, topic, id)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from your_table
where word in
(
    select word
    from your_table
    group by word, topic
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: What if a word exists in other topic also ?

Comment: @Zack My point here is: Let's say that word `minus` occurs twice in `math` topic, and once in `computer` topic. Current answer's subquery would return `minus`. And, `where word in(..)` will fetch the row corresponding to `minus, computer` also (which should not have come)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
          FROM test x 
          JOIN test y 
            ON y.id <> x.id 
           AND y.word = x.word 
           AND y.topic = x.topic;
```